# Using Aerospike without SSD

Tags: hardware, aerospike

Is there a drawback for using [Aerospike](http://aerospike.com) when used in non-SSD server?

Comment: Aerospike claims it's an in-memory database. So why would the harddisk play any role if everything is in memory?

Comment: because it provides hdd persistence feature

Comment: Its a misconception that aerospike is an in-memory database, unless you call SSDs "memory".  It's an flash-optimized database which is intended to exceed RAM, unlike Redis.  Redis uses disk for persistence only - in Aerospike all the indexes need to fit in memory but since you can easily cluster, it's much easier to do than Redis.  It's unfortunate that this is closed because it's a good question.  It might be better reworded like "what are the performance impacts of using aerospike with a non-ssd?"  Aerospike is written specifically to take advantage of SSD, so it's a good question.

Comment: In all fairness, even Aerospike advertises itself as an in-memory database.  From http://www.aerospike.com/products-services/ - "Aerospike has Open Sourced its revolutionary in-memory NoSQL database and key-value store technology." - but I think this is more of a marketing ploy - the next line says "Because Aerospike is flash-optimized with a hybrid RAM/SSD storage architecture, you can get 10x better performance while using 10x fewer servers."

Answer (score 3):

Not at all! Aerospike is a great in-memory key-value store, typically as fast as Redis, but that also scales super easy.

You can check the different configurations possible on Aerospike [here](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/). So if you can fit all your data in memory, Aerospike will work as well or better then any other in-memory database. The SSD optimization is useful for larger data sets that would be too expensive to fully store in memory and Aerospike is also optimized for that use case.

Comment: ah, let me clarify, what I mean by `non-SSD` is conventional harddisk (magnetic)

Comment: Got it, I misunderstood. Well, you will not get anywhere close to the performance you would achieve on SSD if you go with rotational (magnetic) HDs and you may also wear them faster then SSD. (Actually different SSDs also perform at different levels). You can use rotational drives for persisting a 'data in memory' configuration though given the very different access pattern in that case. You can read more about the details on the following links: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/storage.html and http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/ssd/

Comment: you can see performance comparison of redis to aerospike at http://www.aerospike.com/when-to-use-aerospike-vs-redis/ - since it's threaded, it can reach higher throughput without manual sharding.